# SQL how to call user defined function by dynamic variable name

Tags: sql

In SQL - I have list of user defined function names in a table. based on the logic i need to call/exec the function.
Please my high level code logic below,

```
DECLARE @MY_FUNCTION VARCHAR(1000); 
DECLARE @MY_INPUT_PARAMETER INT; 
DECLARE @MY_OUTPUT_PARAMETER INT;

SET @MY_FUNCTION = '' -- Dynamically function name will be provided based on some big logic
--Note: function has input and output parameter

--my query 
-- call the function by @MY_FUNCTION (@MY_INPUT_PARAMETER )
@MY_OUTPUT_PARAMETER = EXEC @MY_FUNCTION (@MY_INPUT_PARAMETER)
--Some big sql script using @MY_OUTPUT_PARAMETER
(
-- Script goes here
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to construct the function with parameters inside the variable and then run sp_execute. Check out the samples in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-using-the-output-parameter

**Important**

However, try to avoid this method of execution if possible. Let the application decide what SP to call and the SP can then use the right function to make the call. There are two advantages to this.

1. Your SP will be compiled and SQL will be able to have an execution plan and continue to fine tune it. Hence, better performance
2. You will have less chances of SQL injections depending on how the table with functions are populated.

Comment: But all my list of function have same input/output parameter only function_name and logic in function differs. even Some big sql script bases on output 'MY_OUTPUT_PARAMETER' has same script(update script) , only the MY_OUTPUT_PARAMETER value will change. So instead writing the same script again and again i am trying to call the function by variable_name. Please assist.

Comment: Certainly you can use sp_execute as I mentioned above. However, the best pattern is to keep the business away from SQL and avoid sp_execute as much as possible. The right solution would be breaking the operation to two parts where the first call made by the application will decide what SP or function to call next. Keep the application intelligent and SPs dumb. SQL is good at querying and not decision making.

Comment: OK Thank you. Will try this.